# Java can't instantiate an Image?

Tags: java, image, awt, instantiation, imageobserver

So for my 2D game I want to use an image to represent a player but when I try to use an image, it tells me that it couldn't be "instantiated". I don't know what that means:

```
public class PlayerOne extends Entity{
  private Image img = new Image();
[...]
  @Override
  public void render(Graphics g){
  g.drawImage( img , x, y, Color.BLUE, new ImageObserver());
  }
}
```

I tried it in another class with BufferedImages but that somehow doesn't work.

So it can't create Objects of neither Image nor the ImageObserver. Does anyone know a fix for this error ?

Comment: "The abstract class Image is the superclass of all classes that represent graphical images. The image must be obtained in a platform-specific manner."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have an image file (*.png for example ) to start with. Then use

```
Image  img = new ImageIcon("img.png").getImage();
```

Comment: thanks but u know how to fix the imageobserver problem aswell xd ?

Comment: I believe ImageObserver is an interface, you should write a class that implements it and instantiates that class.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot instantiate an `abstract class`. Please see [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html).

Following syntax would be operational:

```
private Image image = new BufferedImage(200,200,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
```

Also see [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) for more information on `BufferedImage`. Additionally, here is a tutorial which ilustrates an [example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_dip/java_buffered_image.htm) implementation;